# curl_easy_escape not working from C++ dll

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, curl, libcurl

I am having trouble using the `curl_easy_escape` function in a C++ dll.  If I create a console application, `curl_easy_escape` works as expected.

cURL curl-7.28.1-devel-mingw32
Visual Studio 2010

**Console Application (working as expected)**

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CURL *curl;
    char *data1;
    char *data2;
    int data2len;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        data1 = curl_easy_escape(curl, "this is a string with spaces", 0);
        printf("\r\ndata1 = %s\r\n", data1);
        data2 = curl_easy_unescape(curl, data1, 0, &data2len);
        printf("\r\ndata2 = %s\r\n", data2);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    printf(“\r\nPress any key to continue\r\n”);
    return 0;
```

**Output**

```
data1 = this%20is%20a%20string%20with%20spaces
data2 = this is a string with spaces
Press any key to continue
```

**C++ DLL**

Visual C++ > Win32 > Win32 Project
Application type = DLL (all other options as default)
Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies, added libcurl.lib

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int * curl_test(char *sBuf)
    {
        CURL *curl;
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if (curl)
        {
            // The following line does not work
            //strcpy(sBuf, curl_easy_escape(curl, "this is a string with spaces", 0));

            // This line does work
            strcpy(sBuf, "this is a string with spaces");

            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        }
        return 0;

    }
}
```

The dll is used in a C program and calls `curl_test` with `char ptr[256]`.  With `curl_easy_escape` in place, the `LoadLibrary` call fails:

```
Error: C interpreter run time error: Error -- File error : LoadLibrary(mydll.dll) failed : The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Note that this is on the `LoadLibrary`, so the `curl_test` function has not been called yet.

I suppose I can find some URL encode/decode functions, but would prefer to use what cURL already offers.  I also have the same issue with the `curl_easy_strerror` function.

Could it be the ‘const char *’?

**Update**

Ideally I would like to use `curl_easy_escape/curl_easy_unescape`, but as a workaround I decided to implement my own URL encoding/decoding in C.  I found efficient, well written encoding/decoding functions at http://www.geekhideout.com/urlcode.shtml